# Magento2: How to remove catalogue menu(Main menu) from frontend

Tags: magento2

How to remove catalogue menu from frontend. I will try to xml way its working fine

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

But i need programmatically in php file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment the lines for top menu code in below path

**vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml**

Editing in vendor file is a bad practice, try to override into your custom theme and comment the code which is responsible for rendering menu.

Hope this may help you!!

Comment: Thank you for ur comment. let me check it.

Comment: is it working??

Comment: yes its working

Comment: Great, Pls accept and upvote the answer, Thanks!!

Comment: already i updated as  answer